# AngularJS Test Controller Containing routeChangeSuccess

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am trying to create unit tests to test a navigation list controller, and I'm having issues with creating the tests.

Here is the code for the controller.

```
navListModule.controller('NavListCtrl', ['$scope', 'NavList',
    function ($scope, NavList) {
        $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, routeData) {
            var stationId = routeData.params.stationId;

            if ((stationId !== null) && (stationId !== undefined)) {
                $scope.stationId = stationId;
                var navList = NavList;
                $scope.menuOptions = navList.getMenuOptions(stationId);
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Here is what I've come up with so far in my unit tests.

```
'use strict';

describe('unit testing navListModule', function () {

    var scope, ctrl, location;

    describe('test NavListCtrl', function () {

        beforeEach(module('shipApp.navListModule'));

        // mock NavListService for testing purposes
        var mockNavListService = {
            getMenuOptions: function (stationId) {
                // set default menu options
                var menuOptions = [
                    {
                        name: "Alerts"
                        , pageURL: "alerts"
                    }
                    , {
                        name: "Reports"
                        , pageURL: "reports"
                    }
                    , {
                        name: "Run Close Outs"
                        , pageURL: "closeOuts"
                    }
                ];

                // add admin menu option if stationId set to Admin
                if (stationId.toUpperCase() == 'Admin'.toUpperCase()) {
                    menuOptions.push(
                        {
                            name: "Admin"
                            , pageURL: "admin"
                        }
                    );
                }

                return menuOptions;
            }
        };

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $location) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('NavListCtrl', { $scope: scope, NavList: mockNavListService });
            location = $location;
        }));

        it('should expect stationId to be undefined if stationId not defined in route parameters', function () {
            expect(scope.stationId).toBeUndefined();
        });

        it('should expect scope.$on not to be called if no change in route', function () {
            spyOn(scope, '$on');
            expect(scope.$on).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should expect scope.$on to be called on change in route', function () {
            spyOn(scope, '$on');
            scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, routeData) {});
            expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should expect stationId to be defined in route parameters if route is #/:stationId/path', inject(function ($routeParams) {
            location.path('/Admin/alerts');
            var locationElements = location.path().substring(location.path().indexOf('/') + 1).split('/');
            var stationId = locationElements[0];
            $routeParams.stationId = stationId;
            expect($routeParams.stationId).toEqual('Admin');
        }));

        it('should expect menuOptions array to be returned when getMenuOptions function is called', function () {
            var stationId = 'Admin';
            var menuOptions = NavListCtrl.getMenuOptions(stationId);
        });

    });

});
```

I'm just learning Angular, so I'm not sure if I'm setting up my tests properly.  Should I create tests to ensure that the controller logic does not take place until after the $routeChangeSuccess event occurs?  If so, how do I write such a test?  Also, what is the proper way to test the call for getMenuOptions (last test)?  Please let me know the proper way to test this controller.

Thanks in advance,
Sean

**After playing around with some testing and some help from jvandemo, here is what I have come up with for the unit tests for the controller, as well as the underlying service.  Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.**

```
'use strict';

describe('unit testing navListModule', function () {

    beforeEach(module('shipApp.navListModule'));

    /***** Controllers *****/

    describe('test NavListCtrl', function () {

        var ctrl, scope, NavList, $httpBackend, $location, $route, $routeParams;

        // mock the http backend for routing
        beforeEach(module(function() {
            return function(_$httpBackend_) {
                $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
                $httpBackend.when('GET', 'views/alerts/alerts.html').respond('alerts');
                $httpBackend.when('GET', 'views/alerts/reports.html').respond('reports');
                $httpBackend.when('GET', 'views/alerts/closeOuts.html').respond('closeOuts');
                $httpBackend.when('GET', 'views/alerts/admin.html').respond('admin');
                $httpBackend.when('GET', 'views/shared/error.html').respond('not found');
            };
        }));

        // add $routeProvider mock
        beforeEach(module(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/:stationId/alerts', {
                templateUrl : 'views/alerts/alerts.html',
                controller : 'AlertsCtrl'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/:stationId/reports', {
                templateUrl : 'views/reports/reports.html',
                controller : 'ReportsCtrl'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/:stationId/closeOuts', {
                templateUrl : 'views/closeOuts/closeOuts.html',
                controller : 'CloseOutsCtrl'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/:stationId/admin', {
                templateUrl : 'views/admin/admin.html',
                controller : 'AdminCtrl'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/404', {
                templateUrl : 'views/shared/error.html',
                controller : 'ErrorCtrl'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                redirectTo : '/MasterPl/alerts'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/:stationId', {
                redirectTo : '/:stationId/alerts'
            });
            $routeProvider.when(':stationId', {
                redirectTo : '/:stationId/alerts'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('', {
                redirectTo : '/MasterPl/alerts'
            });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/404'
            });
        }));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$location_, _$route_, _$routeParams_) {
            // mock NavList service
            var mockNavListService = {
                getMenuOptions: function (stationId) {
                    // set default menu options
                    var menuOptions = [
                        {
                            name: "Alerts"
                            , pageURL: "alerts"
                        }
                        , {
                            name: "Reports"
                            , pageURL: "reports"
                        }
                        , {
                            name: "Run Close Outs"
                            , pageURL: "closeOuts"
                        }
                    ];

                    // add admin menu option if stationId set to Admin
                    if (stationId.toUpperCase() == 'Admin'.toUpperCase()) {
                        menuOptions.push(
                            {
                                name: "Admin"
                                , pageURL: "admin"
                            }
                        );
                    }

                    return menuOptions;
                }
            };


            NavList = mockNavListService;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $location = _$location_;
            $route = _$route_;
            $routeParams = _$routeParams_;
            ctrl = $controller('NavListCtrl', { $scope: scope, $routeParams: $routeParams, NavList: NavList });
        }));

        it('should expect stationId and menuOptions to be undefined if stationId not defined in route parameters', function () {
            expect(scope.stationId).toBeUndefined();
            expect(scope.menuOptions).toBeUndefined();
        });

        it('should expect scope.$on not to be called if no change in route', function () {
            spyOn(scope, '$on');
            expect(scope.$on).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should expect scope.$on to be called on change in route', function () {
            spyOn(scope, '$on');
            scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, routeData) {});
            expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should not parse $routeParameters before $routeChangeSuccess', function () {
            $location.path('/Admin/alerts');
            scope.$apply();
            expect(scope.stationId).toBeUndefined();
        });

        it('should expect scope values to be set after $routeChangeSuccess is fired for location /stationId/path', function () {
            $location.path('/Admin/alerts');
            scope.$apply();
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(scope.stationId).toEqual('Admin');
            expect(scope.menuOptions).not.toBeUndefined();
        });

        it('should expect NavList.getMenuOptions() to have been called after $routeChangeSuccess is fired for location /stationId/path', function () {
            spyOn(NavList, 'getMenuOptions').andCallThrough();
            $location.path('/Admin/alerts');
            scope.$apply();
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(NavList.getMenuOptions).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(scope.menuOptions.length).not.toBe(0);
        });

    });


    /***** Services *****/

    describe('test NavList service', function () {

        var scope, NavList;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _NavList_) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            NavList = _NavList_;
        }));

        it('should expect menuOptions array to be returned when getMenuOptions function is called', function () {
            var stationId = 'Admin';
            var menuOptions = NavList.getMenuOptions(stationId);
            expect(menuOptions.length).not.toBe(0);
        });

        it('should expect admin menu option to be in menuOptions if stationId is Admin', function () {
            var stationId = 'Admin';
            var menuOptions = NavList.getMenuOptions(stationId);
            var hasAdminOption = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < menuOptions.length; i++) {
                if (menuOptions[i].name.toUpperCase() == 'Admin'.toUpperCase()) {
                    hasAdminOption = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            expect(hasAdminOption).toBe(true);
        });

        it('should not expect admin menu option to be in menuOptions if stationId is not Admin', function () {
            var stationId = 'MasterPl';
            var menuOptions = NavList.getMenuOptions(stationId);
            var hasAdminOption = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < menuOptions.length; i++) {
                if (menuOptions[i].name.toUpperCase() == 'Admin'.toUpperCase()) {
                    hasAdminOption = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            expect(hasAdminOption).toBe(false);
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a great job here in your tests already. I assume your tests are running correctly (apart from the last test) and will answer your 2 questions separately:

1. `$routeChangeSuccess`: there is no need for you to test core AngularJS functionality. When you depend on `$routeChangeSuccess` to run your code at a certain moment, it is the responsibility of the AngularJS team and their test suite to ensure that `$routeChangeSuccess` works correctly.
2. `getMenuOptions()`: since this method is part of a service you are injecting, you can create a separate unit test that tests the `NavList` service and move the last test to that suite. Since you are unit testing, it is a good practice to create a separate test suite for each component (controller, service, etc) to keep things well organized and compact.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, jvandemo.  Regarding your comments, should I mock up the NavListService, or is it okay to directly inject the service into my controller tests?  Is there a better way to test that the stationId is returned in the location.path rather than parsing the string?  In other words, should I test that stationId is part of $routeParams, and how would I test such?  Lastly, in your 2nd bullet point, you mention that I should test getMenuOptions in my service tests.  However, is there any need to test that the controller has values in the menuOptions scope variable in the controller tests?

Comment: Hi Sean, the comment box doesn't allow me to type code or line breaks, so I'll try to write a concise answer: 1. I would mock the NavListService in your controller unit test as you are testing your controller there, not your service, unless your service contains the data statically and your unit test can safely depend on it (and thus no mock is required). 2. If setting and getting the value of menuOptions requires controller logic, you can test it in the controller unit test. In short: try to isolate your tests to the unit you are testing. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank for the continuing help.  I have updated my code for the unit tests.  All tests pass.  Am I missing anything with my tests?  Also, what is happening when I create a new $controller object with the ctrl = $controller(...) line?  I can leave out everything after $scope: scope, and it works the same.  I had seen in other posts where the $controller object contained references to all function parameters in the controller definition.  Is that necessary?

Comment: You're welcome. The $controller is used for instantiating a controller object. If you don't use the instantiated object in your test code, then there is no need to instantiate it in the first place. Hope that helps!