# How to test routing with AngularJS and Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

My routing looks like:

```
angular.module('mean').config(['$routeProvider', '$translateProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $translateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/items', {
      templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
      controller: 'ItemsController'
    }).
    when('/items/create', {
      templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
      controller: 'ItemsController'
    }).

    when('/articles/create', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles/create.html'
    }).
    when('/articles/:articleId/edit', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles/edit.html'
    }).
    when('/articles/:articleId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles/view.html'
    }).
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/index.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: '/lang/',
      suffix: '.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en-US');
    $translateProvider.useCookieStorage();
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
  }
]);
```

Basically, I want to write tests to ensure that every route has a template and a controller.

Comment: Consider extracting all that into a constant aka angular.module('mean').const. By the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to test that routing works, the angular codebase already does, for some useful tests you could look at this example:

[AngularJS Test Controller Containing routeChangeSuccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236809/angularjs-test-controller-containing-routechangesuccess)